# Link from Excel to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a view on SQL 2008 which I will then use to read from it using excel (Data-->from other sources-->from SQL Server..).

But the problem is that I have many records in the view and I only need the newest records only.

Excel  can only display the first 65,534 items.
[image]

For example, as shown in  “excel link to sql” image, the last date displayed is in 2013, but I need the  newest records descending starting 2015 and below.

I tried to sort the records in descending order(as show in the “view“ image) from the view but still it gives me the date from the oldest records.

Comment: Which one you are using `xls` or `xlsx`?

Comment: It's not true (no more) that Excel can only display 65534 rows. But this is not the problem. I think the problem is the view query. Can you show us the query?

Comment: Have you tried sorting the  **pivot** column in descending order? Hover the cursor over the top of the column until a small black arrow appears. Right click and select "Sort"